# remote devices supervision

Tags: python, monitoring, snmp

This is a more comprehensive post than my [last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049530/client-server-json-communication-with-python).

I want to monitor devices using python so:

- i've a remote agent which, with sensors, will get device datas such as disks usage, processes etc.
- a server get datas from remote agents and store them into DBs
- a website allows you to see these data

What i already have:

- psutil to get device informations
- MySQL + NoSQL to store devices datas
- django as website to see stored data

What i need:

- how to communicatite between remote agents and server. I've already read doc about, zmq, twisted, rpc-json, tornado but i don't know which is the best regarding to my project
- possibility to schedule transferts to avoid overloads
- secure connections

PS: in an ideal way, i'd like to code my agent with standard python library.

Any idea about?

Comment: What kind of devices? Servers?

Comment: servers yes, but why not others devices like in the future.

Comment: I just didn't know if you meant "coffeemakers." :)

Comment: i don't need this :) only servers

Answer (score 1):

FYI I'll use [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) protocole now i've to found how to implement with Python