# is snmp required

Tags: python, monitoring, snmp

is snmp really required to manage devices ?
i'd like to script something with python to manage devices (mainly  servers), such as disk usage, process list etc.
i'm learning how to do and many article speak about snmp protocole.

I can't use, for example, psutil, or subprocess or os modules, and send information via udp ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SNMP is a standard monitoring (and configuration) tool used widely in managing network devices (but not only). I don't understand your question fully - is it a problem that you cannot use SNMP because device does not support it (what does it support then?) To script anything you have to know what interface is exposed to you (if not a MIB files then what?). Did you read about NETCONF?

Comment: thanx for your answer. I really don't know what to do, the main id is to deploy an agent on customers devices and monitor them. you can see my initial post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058099/remote-devices-supervision

Comment: If you're going to deploy an agent then SNMP makes no sense because its main advantage is that you don't need to install or run anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not *required*, but your question is sort of like asking if you're required to use http to serve web pages.  Technically you don't *need* it, but if you don't use it you're giving up interoperability with a lot of existing client software.

Comment: i know it's like these kind of questions, thanks for your patience. It's a new world to me and i'm looking to the "best" solution building an agent without external libs.