# Python and queue

Tags: python, queue

This question is related to [this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058099/remote-devices-supervision/12079718#12079718).

I have to send device information in json format to a server. However, I'm concerned about what will happen if i can't connect to the remote server? I don't want to loose data, so I thought that each datum could be in a queue. A connection thread could parse the queue and send data to server. In my opinion this is a better solution than having a connection thread which sends data directly. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like a queue is always suitable to decouple things. Especially when the processing of data can be deferred. A queue implementation like RabbitMQ is transactional so you it will integrate nicely into a system where transactional integrity is a must.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In fact i'd like using stdlib in the agent (script which monitor a device) and use twisted on the server side then i cannot use neither Zmq or RabbitMq

Answer (score 0):

Right, you might want a persistent queue-like storage between the application components. Depending on your requirements it might be anything ranging from the simple file to fully fledged transactional storage.

Comment: cf my comment behind the other response. Using stdlib for the agent, twisted for the server :)